# Jump start car blow multi fuse and radio

Tags: jump-start

Car was jump started with jump start pack, blew multi fuse and destroyed radio/ audio system. The owner of company that jump started the car stated that the safety features on the portable machine make it impossible to incorrectly attach cables. However damage was done. My questions: are there faulty portable jump start systems, inherent problems with 2013 Kia Soul, or just general electrical system failure. Would consider the radio/ audio system needs new fuse too, seems like 2 different fuses according to owners manual. Would have thought dealership would have checked all fuses but it is Kia after all. 10A 15A fuse

Comment: They are responsible for the damage, doubt there is anything you can do to force them to do anything for you outside of a courtroom.

Comment: I find it near impossible for your average jump packs to blow fuses when used properly, even when momentarily hooked in reverse they do not generally blow fuses. Why did you need a boost in the first place, this may be a better path to look into of what could have caused the issue's.

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally it is possible to blow fuses or some electronics equipment while boosting even with the cables attached properly (+ to +, - to ground). 
In my opinion, what you are describing is not necessarily the fault of the road assistance company.

Answer (score -4):

NEVER ADD A NEGATIVE GROUND FROM BATTERY TO BATTERY OR A CHARGER FIND A GROUND ON THE MOTOR correct if wrong if a spark surges through your system via the coil or regulator into the computer does this blow fuses and possibly ruin your computer for safety from such an occurrence find a ground like the motor ground least that what my Nissan manual reads sometimes the alternator could short out like putting the  positive wire on the wrong side of the alternator lol as far as shorting out inside the car think there is a tool you can buy that beeps like a sonar faster as you get closer to the short

Comment: "correct if wrong if a spark surges through your system via the coil or regulator into the computer does this blow fuses and possibly ruin your computer"....
Most modern ecu's have built in transient voltage protection so its more likely to blow the external fuses then damage the actual ecu's. Don't get me wrong it happens, but not as often as people would lead you to believe.